# Making multiple pivot items visible depending case

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

what I want to do is that based in a cell the pivot items change

For example 
if the selected cell has February as value I want that every pivot table in the field month filter by Jan and Feb or

if the selected cell has May as value I want that every pivot table in the field month filter by Jan, Feb, Mar, April and May

This is the code that I have but the problem is that shows problems with the property visible of pivotitem

Then I assign the different cases in the code

```
Sub skicer()

Dim PT As PivotTable
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Field As PivotField

Set ws = Worksheets("PyG Tecnico")

        For Each PT In ws.PivotTables
        'MsgBox PT.Name
        Set Field = PT.PivotFields("Month")
        Field.ClearAllFilters
        With Field
            .PivotItems("Jan").visible = True
            .PivotItems("Feb").visible = False
            .PivotItems("Mar").visible = False
            .PivotItems("April").visible = False
            .PivotItems("May").visible = False
            .PivotItems("Jun").visible = False
            .PivotItems("Jul").visible = False
            .PivotItems("August").visible = False
            .PivotItems("Sept").visible = False
            .PivotItems("Oct").visible = False
            .PivotItems("Nov").visible = False
            .PivotItems("Dic").visible = False
        End With
    Next PT

End Sub
```

**Thanks for your help**

Comment: If it's based on the same data cache you may be able to just use a timeline slicer, no?

Comment: @MarkS. They are different datasets and these can't join. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach:

```
Sub skicer()

    Dim PT As PivotTable
    Dim Field As PivotField, mSel, bShow As Boolean, m

    mSel = Selection.Cells(1).Value 'selected month

    For Each PT In Worksheets("PyG Tecnico").PivotTables

        Set Field = PT.PivotFields("Month")
        Field.ClearAllFilters
        bShow = True

        For Each m In Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "April", "May", "Jun", "Jul", _
                            "August", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dic")

            Field.PivotItems(m).Visible = bShow
            If m = mSel Then bShow = False 'later months do not show...

        Next m

    Next PT

End Sub
```

Comment: What error?  If you're having a specific problem with your code it's best to describe exacly what error message you get, and which line it occurs on.

Comment: This is what Excel shows
Error '1004': Unable to set the Visible property of the PivotItem class

Comment: "and which line it occurs on"

Comment: In this one friend

*Field.PivotItems(m).Visible = bShow*


The same error that happens with my code

Comment: What's the value of m when that happens, and is there definitely an item with that name ?  If you could share a workbook which shows this problem it would be useful - this type of problem can be tricky to debug remotely.

Comment: m = Dic and yes there is an item with the name
In this moment I can upload files but maybe I can share with you by email